# Ringtone continues playing when ListPreference value changes

Tags: java, android, ringtone, listpreference

I have list of target values in ListPreference and I need to play sound when int i exceeds it (target value).

```
  String limit = sharedPreferences.getString("limit", getString(R.string.limitdef));
  switch (limit) {
            case "20":
                if (i >= 20) {
                    this.lets_dance();
                } else {
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
                        ringtone.stop();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "30":
                if (i >= 30) {
                    this.lets_dance();
                } else {
                    if (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
                        ringtone.stop();
                    } 
                }
                break;
    }
```

void lets_dance:

```
  private void lets_dance() {
            if (!ringtone.isPlaying()) {
                ringtone.play();
            }
    }
```

And now my problem:
for example when I start the app and target value is "20", but then I change my mind and cahnge it to "30",  ringtone still starts playing when int i is >=20.

Comment: why are you using limit if the event are dependent on i then use that in swith case

Comment: I need to change target value in settings, basically I`m developing speed limit, so I need to be able to change that target value

Comment: then using while loop would be suitable

Comment: I tried using while instead of if, deleted else and the problem is still there

Comment: I also tried using while insted of switch and all cases: it causes app to shut down